# Root user no longer exists

Tags: macos, passwords, user-accounts, sudo, root

I'm running macOS Server 5.6.1 on High Sierra (10.13.4) and I was trying to modify a system launch daemon plist file the other day as my apache installation wasn't working after migration. `sudo` wouldn't allow me to change anything due to SIP restrictions, so I decided that I'd try to get a root login shell and try to modify the plist file that way. I'd previously enabled the root user years ago when I first got the computer. I opened a Terminal window and tried `login root` and entering the password. Nothing. I tried a few different possible passwords but none of them worked.

At this point, I figure that I must have forgotten which of the dozens of passwords I used for the root account. No problem, though, because I can reset the root password, right? So I open Directory Utility, authenticate, and click "Change Root Password..." in the menu. I try logging in again—to no avail.

I'm a little confused now, but I decide to try disabling the root user in the menu and then re-enable it. However, clicking on "Disable root user" does nothing, and it never changes back to "Enable root user". Trying `dsenableroot -d` returns `dsenableroot:: ***Failed to disable root user.` Slightly concerned now, I try [`sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/root`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257659/why-would-dsenableroot-not-work-on-a-10-7-5-osx-server#257688), but that fails with the message `<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)`. I also try `sudo passwd root`, which gives me `passwd: Unknown user name 'root'.`

Now I'm very worried. How on earth could the root user just disappear?? `top` and the Activity Monitor show plenty of processes owned by root, but `dscl . -list /Users UniqueID` doesn't have an entry for root, or a UID of `0`. In fact, as far as I can tell, the root user **simply does not exist**. Even in the File Info dialogs in Finder, files and folders owned by root show "Fetching..." in the area where the owner name should be (see image).

[image: Finder file info dialog]

As I don't use this computer on a daily basis, and certainly don't log on as root often, I have no idea when this started or for how long I've not had a root user. I'm pretty sure it's been at least a month or two, but other than that I don't know.

Can someone please help me figure out what the heck is going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Is SIP enabled?

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah.

Comment: Disable & try again, root & SIP don't mix. `csrutil disable` from Terminal in Recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin Tried it, but none of the above worked :/

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas. I haven't used root itself in 10 years or more. I tend to just use sudo. Maybe run [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) over the disk perms?